# Integrating factor for $(y^3+ty^2+y)dt+(t^3+t^2y+t)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation  $(y^3+ty^2+y)dt+(t^3+t^2y+t)dy=0$ is not exact, as it turns out it is $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^3+ty^2+y)=3y^2+2ty+1$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(t^3+t^2y+t)=3t^2+2ty+1$

I attempted muliplying both sides of the equation by a factor $u(y)$ which after taking the partial derivatives led to $u'(y)[y^3+ty^2+y]=3u(y)[t^2-y^2]$ for which there are no obvious solutions. Using a factor $u(t)$ leads to similar results.

Using a factor $u(t,y)$ leads to a partial differential equation, which is too hard to solve.

How can I find the appropriate factor to make the equation exact and nice?

Answer (score 1):

$$(y^3+ty^2+y)dt+(t^3+t^2y+t)dy=0$$
Regroup some terms:
$$d(ty)+(y^3+ty^2)dt+(t^3+t^2y)dy=0$$
Multiply by  2:
$$2d(ty)+(2y^3+2ty^2)dt+(2t^3+2t^2y)dy=0$$
Rearrange some terms:
$$2d(ty)+(t^2dy^2+y^2dt^2)+(2y^3dt+2t^3dy)=0$$
$$2d(ty)+d(ty)^2+2(y^3dt+t^3dy)=0$$
The integrating factor is now obvious:
$$\mu (t,y)=\dfrac 1 {t^3y^3}$$
The differential equation becomes:
$$2\dfrac {d(ty)}{t^3y^3}+\dfrac {d(ty)^2}{t^3y^3}+2\left(\dfrac {dt}{t^3}+\dfrac {dy}{y^3} \right)=0$$
$$\left(\dfrac {1}{t^3y^3}+\dfrac {1}{t^2y^2}\right)d(ty)+\dfrac {dt}{t^3}+\dfrac {dy}{y^3} =0$$
Integrate.